# bash syntax error - operand expected -Need help understanding why?

Tags: bash, math

I'm still very green with arithmetic in bash. I got some help cleaning up a 2 part query to get a specific value from a linux box i have. However, I now receive a syntax error I can't seem to piece together. Any help understanding why would be greatly appreciated.

The query is:

```
echo $(( (2147483633-"$(grep -i isrs /proc/zem0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$')")/5184000 ))
```

and the error comes back as

```
-bash: (2147483633-"16458074")/5184000 : syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""16458074")/5184000 ")
```

please help me understand why! thanks so much, in advance!

Comment: Your behavior here is going to be undefined if the grep comes back with no results, or more than one result.

Comment: Can you lose the double-quotes?  `echo $(( (2147483633-"16458074")/5184000 ))` works fine for me, but `echo $(( (2147483633-"16458074")/5184000 ))` gives me the same error you're getting.

Comment: *nod*. The double-quotes would be harmless if the assignment from the command substitution were done as a separate step, but inside a math context things are different.

Comment: it was the double quotes! thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the quotes

Try this:

```
echo $(( (2147483633-$(grep -i isrs /proc/zem0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$'))/5184000 ))
```

**Update**

Because

```
echo $(( (2147483633-"$(grep -i isrs /proc/zem0 | grep -Eo '[0-9]+$')")/5184000 ))
```

translates to

```
echo $(( (2147483633-"some_number")/5184000 ))
```

and having quotes around numbers is not valid for arithmetic operations

Comment: ...translates to that _in a math context_. The expansion would be different (the quotes would be removed during syntax parsing rather than treated as data) in a non-math context; it's perhaps worth being precise.